# jshint vimrc SpellBad customization does not stick

Tags: vim, jshint

Using

```
" Customize jshint highlights 
hi clear SpellBad
hi SpellBad cterm=underline,bold ctermfg=white ctermbg=black
```

I was able to customize my jshint `SpellBad` highlights to the colors I desire when I first open a buffer containing jshint errors. As can be seen here, my background is black and the line with the error is in bold white and underlined. Exactly as I specified using those definitions in `.vimrc` above.

[image]

The problem is, when I switch around between buffers or open a that buffer later again, my custom jshint `SpellBad` colors no longer apply and I get the "default" colors which I do not want.

[image]

Why is this so? And how do I make my custom jshint `SpellBad` colors stick?

Comment: The only thing I can think of is that something changed your color scheme when you switched buffers. I do not believe the custom high lighting should go away just because you changed buffers.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Because your custom highlight settings will be cleared after every `:colorscheme` commands.

try:

```
autocmd ColorScheme * hi clear SpellBad
    \| hi SpellBad cterm=underline,bold ctermfg=white ctermbg=black
```

Comment: I see what you mean. But somehow, when I add this to my `.vimrc`, my custom highlights fail completely (does not load even for the first time).

Comment: Please make sure you put the `autocmd` lines before your `colorscheme` setting in `.vimrc`.

Comment: Ok. Placing the `autocmd` lines before `colorscheme` allows the first load to work fine; but subsequent switch in buffers still result in my custom highlights for `SpellBad` reverting to the "default" pinkish colors.

Comment: That's odd.  Could you paste your entire `.vimrc` please?

Comment: ok, I got it. Remove the section labeled `This caters for the scenario when vimdiff is called while inside a vim buffer` from your `.vimrc`, then it works.